# Magento 1 - Which file is responsible for displaying products in category page?

Tags: magento-1.9, category

I am trying to find the file which is responsible for displaying products into category page
In magento 1.

But i am not able to find it
Any help appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

/app/design/frontend/your_theme/template/catalog/product/list.phtml

Comment: Thanks but tt has -                     <?php echo $this->getChild('product.list.item')->setIndexer(false)->setProduct($product)->toHtml() ?>